# Как сделать в swift один тип для зависимых свойств?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, enum

Нужно сделать примерно такую структуру, т.е. лепестки зависят от веток

```
enum Cars {
    enum Toyota: String {
        case Camry
        case Avensis
        case Corolla
        case Avalon
    }
    enum Mercedes: String {
        case S_600
        case G_65_AMG
        case C_63_AMG
    }
    enum Volkswagen: String {
        case Passat
        case Golf
        case Touareg
        case Polo
        case Vento
        case Jetta
    }
}

Cars.Toyota.Avensis // Avensis, но эта строка не говорит что тойота
```

Может надо как-то вместе со *структурой* сделать?

От нового типа нужно:

1. Работа со *switch* по всей структуре, чтоб можно было работать не
   только с моделями, но и с марками, например, со всеми тойотами
2. Можно хранить в БД и "поднимать" этот тип из строки, или как-то еще, в общем нужно чтоб в БД хранили что-то вроде "Toyota.Camry" и из этой строки получили этот новый тип

Только изучаю *swift*, совсем не было опыта со *структурами* и *перечислениями*. В книжке и статьях что нашел только элементарные примеры.
Может я вообще не туда пошел?

Comment: чтоб можно было работать не только с моделями, но и с марками. Что Вы под этим подразумеваете? В каком контексте будет это использоваться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоем случае лучше сделать так. Есть древовидный plist с машинами и моделями (схема на картинке).
Сам экземпляр машины представляет собой класс, enum, NSDictionary с двумя текстовыми полями name и model. В базе можно так и хранить (эти два поля)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
    }

Comment: Спасибо. Это намного лучше, чем сделал я. Проблемы только с сортировкой, но думаю смогу это решить. еще раз спасибо!